# the_content altering outputted HTML?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress plugin (wp youtube lyte) that hooks into the "the_content" filter, adds some HTML and returns the content.

The resulting rendered HTML is slightly different from what I added, with linebreaks being added after opening or closing divs and -more importantly- unbalanced tags being added, even when no other plugin is active.

I've tried removing the "wpautop" filter, but that seems not to change anything.

I can't find any documentation on what might be happening, hope someone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: The plugin itself might add unbalanced HTML. You'll probably have more luck asking in their support forum.

Comment: no unbalanced HTML in the plugin, no :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was with [wpautop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) after all, which does some pretty nasty stuff to the HTML when meta- or noscript-tags are involved.